# Can't resolve all parameters for AnalysisComponent: ([object Object], ?, ?, [

Tags: angular, typescript

First of all i am beginner at angular framework.

When i added project's services then i get that error.

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AnalysisComponent: ([object Object], ?, ?, [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]).

Angular 4.0.0

I cant understand how to resolve it.

calendar.component.ts:

```
    import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Inject, ViewChild, TemplateRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
    import { InternService } from '../intern.service';
    import { AuthService } from '../../user/auth.service';
    import { ToastrService } from '../../common/toastr.service';
    import { IIntern } from '../intern';

    import {
      startOfDay,
      endOfDay,
      subDays,
      addDays,
      endOfMonth,
      isSameDay,
      isSameMonth,
      addHours
    } from 'date-fns';

    import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

    import {
      CalendarEvent,
      CalendarEventAction,
      CalendarEventTimesChangedEvent
    } from 'angular-calendar';

    const colors: any = {
      red: {
        primary: '#ad2121',
        secondary: '#FAE3E3'
      },
      blue: {
        primary: '#1e90ff',
        secondary: '#D1E8FF'
      },
      yellow: {
        primary: '#e3bc08',
        secondary: '#FDF1BA'
      }
    };

    export interface IEvent {
      start: Date,
      end: Date,
      title: string,
      color: { primary: string, secondary: string },
      actions: CalendarEventAction[]
    }

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-fullcalendar',
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
      templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.scss']
    })
    export class AnalysisComponent implements OnInit {

      @ViewChild('modalContent') modalContent: TemplateRef<any>;

      view = 'month';

      viewDate: Date = new Date();

      modalData: {
        action: string,
        event: CalendarEvent
      };

      actions: CalendarEventAction[] = [{
        label: '<i class="editButton"></i>',
        onClick: ({ event }: { event: CalendarEvent }): void => {
          this.handleEvent('Edited', event);
        }
      }, {
        label: '<i class="deleteButton"></i>',
        onClick: ({ event }: { event: CalendarEvent }): void => {
          this.events = this.events.filter(iEvent => iEvent !== event);
          this.handleEvent('Deleted', event);
        }
      }];

      refresh: Subject<any> = new Subject();

      events: CalendarEvent[] = [];

      ngOnInit() {
        this.internService.getInternsByOption('all')
          .subscribe(data => {
            if (data.success === false) {
              if (data.errcode) {
                this.authService.logout();
                this.router.navigate(['login']);
              }
              this.toastr.error(data.message);
            } else {
              console.log(data.data);
            }
          });
      }

      activeDayIsOpen = true;

      constructor(private modal: NgbModal,
        private iintern: IIntern, private ievent: IEvent,
        private internService: InternService,
        private toastr: ToastrService,
        private router: Router,
        private authService: AuthService,
        @Inject(DOCUMENT) doc: any) { }

      dayClicked({ date, events }: { date: Date, events: CalendarEvent[] }): void {

        if (isSameMonth(date, this.viewDate)) {
          if (
            (isSameDay(this.viewDate, date) && this.activeDayIsOpen === true) ||
            events.length === 0
          ) {
            this.activeDayIsOpen = false;
          } else {
            this.activeDayIsOpen = true;
            this.viewDate = date;
          }
        }
      }

      eventTimesChanged({ event, newStart, newEnd }: CalendarEventTimesChangedEvent): void {
        event.start = newStart;
        event.end = newEnd;
        this.handleEvent('Dropped or resized', event);
        this.refresh.next();
      }

      handleEvent(action: string, event: CalendarEvent): void {
        this.modalData = { event, action };
        this.modal.open(this.modalContent, { size: 'lg' });
      }

      addEvent(): void {
        this.events.push({
          title: 'New event',
          start: startOfDay(new Date()),
          end: endOfDay(new Date()),
          color: colors.red,
          draggable: true,
          resizable: {
            beforeStart: true,
            afterEnd: true
          }
        });
        this.refresh.next();
      }

      eventCreator(eventintern: IIntern) {
        let a = this.ievent;
        a.start = eventintern.starteddate;
        a.end = eventintern.endeddate;
        a.color = colors.red;
        a.actions = this.actions;
        this.events.push(a);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
constructor(private modal: NgbModal,
    private iintern: IIntern, private ievent: IEvent,
    private internService: InternService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) doc: any) { }
```

remove the following from your constructor `private iintern: IIntern, private ievent: IEvent` and `@Inject(DOCUMENT) doc: any`, I'm not entirely sure what that `doc` is being used for?

The only line I see being used from the removed items is `private ievent: IEvent`. If you require these to be used as varibales, you would add them to the top of your component like so:

```
export class AnalysisComponent implements OnInit {
  public event: IEvent;
  public intern: IIntern;
  public doc: DOCUMENT;
```

Your constructor should look like this:

```
constructor(private modal: NgbModal,
    private internService: InternService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService) { }
```

Comment: I think his problem is interfaces `private iintern: IIntern, private ievent: IEvent,`

Comment: Sory for my spagetti. Its not resolved same error again.

Comment: @yurzui I was busy updating my answer while you commented :)

Comment: @TahsinGül no problem, glad I could help